# An Isomorphism for the Tensor Product in Infinite Dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

For finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$, we have that $V \cong V^{**}$ and that $V^* \otimes W \cong \text{Hom}(V,W)$. We can then combine these two isomorphisms to get 
$$
(1) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ V \otimes W \cong V^{**} \otimes W \cong \text{Hom}(V^*, W)
$$

Now, let $V$ and $W$ be two *infinite-dimensional* vector spaces, and define $\text{Hom}_{\ fin}(V,W)$ to be the finite-rank homomorphisms from $V$ to $W$. I know that we have an isomorphism $V^* \otimes W \cong \text{Hom}_{\ fin}(V,W)$.

**Question:** Can we recover a result that generalizes $(1)$? For example, do we have $V \otimes W \cong \text{Hom}_{\ fin}(V^*,W)$?

I believe the map $\mu: V \otimes W \to \text{Hom}_{\ fin}(V^*,W)$ defined by 
$$
v \otimes w \to (f \to f(v)w)
$$
gives an injection; however, I have doubts about this map being a surjection. I have a feeling that surjectivity would rely on $V \cong V^{**}$, which we don't have in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: It should probably work if you take $\hom_{\mathrm {Fin}}(V,\mathbb k)$ as $V^*$, but in general the right hand side is much larger than $V\otimes W$.

Comment: In the case I'm interested in, I have a grading $V = \bigoplus_\lambda V_\lambda$ where $\text{dim}(V_\lambda)<\infty$. Then if we set
$$
V^\vee := \bigoplus_\lambda V^*_\lambda
$$
the "graded" dual of $V$, I believe (although I could be mistaken) that $V^\vee = \text{Hom}_{\ fin}(V,\mathbb{k})$. If so, you are suggesting that one could possibly instead consider $\text{Hom}_{\ fin}(V^\vee,W)$? My intuition and knowledge of infinite-dimensional linear algebra is embarrassingly lacking, so I would have to work through the details.